# Аргументы в C и их свойства

Tags: c

Интересует как реализовать следующие: я стартую программу с помощью `./programm_name` через консоль и к примеру ввожу `-t 15` для указания параметра, в моем случае, это продолжительность. При выводе должно указывать число 15, вместо нуля.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int durationTime = 0;
    //код
    if(strcmp(argv[i], "-t")) == 0) {
        printf("\nnew duration Time is - %d\n", durationTime);
```

Comment: ты передаешь **два** параметра: `-t` и `15` проверить это можешь с помощью значения `argc`

Comment: @Grundy `argc` не 3 покажет? нулевой - название программы не считает разве в Си?

Comment: @teran, вполне может быть :)

Comment: @teran - 0 это сама программа, 1 первый аргумент, 2 второй аргумент и тд) вопрос в том, как это будет работать если будет больше аргументов.

Comment: @Insider вам в комментариях к ответу ниже уже предложили использовать `getopt()`. Если у вас может передаваться несколько параметров, так и пишите в вопросе. Если хотите написать получение параметров самостоятельно, то очевидно необходимо перебрать массив `argv` в поисках значения `-t` и взять следующий по списку элемент в качестве значения, проверив его на валидность/

Comment: @teran тогда думаю следует задать дополнительный вопрос про функционал `getopt()`. Вижу его впервые.

Comment: @Insider справку прочитайте прежде чем вопросы задавать.

Comment: @Insider, если кроме `-t` допустимы и другие аргументы без значений, например, `-v` и `-h`, то все еще более усложняется. Скажем, такие вызовы `./a.out -hvt15` `./a.out -v -ht 15` тоже вполне допустимы. Все это  разбирает `getopt` (`getop_long`), а также можете посмотреть на `argp_parse`. Вообще, про аргументы командной строки и как их разбирать (getopt или argp) можно почитать [тут](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html#Argument-Syntax)

Comment: Если интересно, сам я пользуюсь [вот этой штукой](http://pastebin.com/Tn97nSPL), которая может "автоматически" присваивать значения аргументов переменным в программе и аналогично `argp_parse` выводить help по описанию аргументов (но, к сожалению, для нее нет документации).

Comment: @avp довольно занятно.. надо будет попробовать )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте значение `argv[2]`

```
int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
  int durationTime = 0;
  //код
  if (argc >= 3 && strcmp(argv[1], "-t") == 0) {
    durationTime = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("\nnew duration Time is - %d\n", durationTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: А почему не использовать `getopt`?

Comment: в вашем случае, два раза будет выдавать строку `printf`

Comment: @Insider два раза то вы откуда взяли?

Comment: @teran всего лишь выполнил код )

Answer (score 5):

Настоятельно рекомендую не изобретать деревянный велосипед с треугольными колёсами, а воспользоваться функцией getopt_long, применяемой во всех промышленных разработках. Нечто вроде:

```
#include <getopt.h>

extern char *optarg;
extern int optind, opterr, optopt;

struct param pr;

// Разбор параметров командной строки
// argc и argv - из функции main.
int ParseParam(int argc, char **argv) {
        int c;
        int option_index = -1;

        static struct option long_options[] = {
                {"duration",      required_argument, 0, 't' },
                 . . .
                {0,         0,                 0,  0 }
        };

        // Задаём значения по умолчанию:
        memset(&pr, sizeof(struct param), 0);
        pr.t = 0;
        . . .

        // Разбор опций командной строки
        while (1) {
                c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "t: . . .",long_options, &option_index);
                if (c == -1) break;

                switch (c) {
                        case 't':
                                pr.d = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        . . .
                        default:
                                printf("Ошибочная опция командной строки\n");
                                return -1;
                }
                option_index = -1;
        }

        return 0;
};
```

Многоточие надо заменить на остальные параметры, а структура pr - это Ваша структура для введённых параметров.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае пользователь может ввести аргументы как через пробел, например,

```
program_name -t 15
```

так и слитно, как один аргумент,

```
program_name -t15
```

Причем числовое значение также может быть введено с ошибкой. Например

```
program_name -t 15A
```

К тому же надо проверять, что общее число аргументов не больше, чем требуется задать.

Все это усложняет проверку аргументов.

Прямолинейный подход может выглядеть следующим образом

```
int durationTime = 0;
int valid_args = 1;


if (argc > 1 )
{
    if ( ( valid_args = strncmp( argv[1], "-t", 2 ) == 0 ) )
    {
        char *p;
        if ((valid_args = argv[1][2] == '\0' && argc == 3))
        {
            p = argv[2];
        }
        else if ((valid_args = argv[1][2] != '\0' && argc == 2))
        {
            p = argv[1] + 2;
        }

        if (valid_args)
        {
            char *tail;
            durationTime = (int)strtol(p, &tail, 10);
            valid_args = *tail == '\0';
        }
    }
}

if (!valid_args) puts("Error: incorrect arguments."
    "\nUsage: program [-t duration]");
```

Answer (score 0):

немного изменил код @anton-shchyrov и все работает как надо. Вот кому интересно )

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    int durationTime = 15;
    int ret = 0;
    int sampleRate = 48000;
    int startCapture = 0;
    int mainHeight = 1280;
    int mainWidth = 720;
    int previewHeight = 640;
    int previewWidth = 480;
    char captureFormat[7] = "format";


    if (argc == 1) {
        help();
    }
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-h") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--help") == 0)) {
            help();
        }
        if (argc >= 3 && (strcmp(argv[i], "-t") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--time") == 0)) {
            durationTime = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            startCapture++;
        }
        if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--capture") == 0)) {
            startCapture++;
        }
        if (argc >= 3 && (strcmp(argv[i], "-a") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--audio") == 0)) {
            sampleRate = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            startCapture++;
        }
        if(argc >= 3 && (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--resolution") == 0)){
            mainHeight = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            mainWidth = atoi(argv[i + 2]);
            startCapture++;
        }
        if(argc >= 3 && (strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--image") == 0)){
            previewHeight = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            previewWidth = atoi(argv[i + 2]);
            startCapture++;
        }
        if(argc >= 3 && (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "--format") == 0)){
            startCapture++;
        }
    }
    if (startCapture > 0) {
        //код 
  }
}
```